# how to pack a section of machine code as a function in .o object file

Tags: object, compilation, elf, riscv, low-level-code

GOAL: Given a section of machine code, which conatins RISC-V extended instructions, I want to wrap it as a function and create an .o object file.

The function is something like **void foo()**, there's no arguments with void return type. and it call no other external functions and needs no relocation.
How do I achieve that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [.incbin](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Incbin.html) assembly directive. [Example 1](https://gist.github.com/mmozeiko/ed9655cf50341553d282). [Example 2](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53773555/50617).

You'll need to adjust the section name to something like `.text.foo` and section attributes to make the code executable.

Comment: sorry I didn't know there's a check mark to accept it. just aceepted it! thanks a lot